# Newly added Drupal cck fields are created but not shown when published

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, cck

I have a content type which has several fields. When I add new fields to this content type, they get added. I am able to enter data into these newly created fields. But when I publish it, the previously existing fields are shown. But the newly created fields do not appear.
I have checked the permission, cleared the cache.
Am not much aware of using view module. But there exist a view for this content type. Is that responsible for it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the page where you want to see your fields is handle by Views, yep definitivly need to look into this views. There a lot of chance that the views only display fields (at the opposite of "full node" or "teaser"), and the fields it display are set in the views configuration.

Comment: Hi Haza,Thanks for the help. The display is not page but a full node viewe.

Comment: Be sure the field is not hidden on this page "?q=admin/content/node-type/[CONTENT TYPE]/display" (d6 url, for D7 admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT TYPE]/display)

Comment: Hi Haza, confirmed. Not hidden or excluded

Comment: So, maybe some "bad output rewrite" stuff in a custom module or template.php (or even worst, in the .tpl.php file)

Comment: When I create a new content type, and add a new field to it, that field gets published. But the problem is only with this field. Also, the field appears when I preview it in view preview.

Answer (score 0):

Some modules will allow granular permissions per cck field.

You might check the user permissions page and see if there is a checkbox for "view {CUSTOM FIELD}" or "edit {CUSTOM FIELD}".

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it is. Actually in the file node.tpl.php , there was an exception for the content type 'article' to print only the predefined fields. So, the newly created fields were not getting printed. But when I added the php code for printing these newly added fields, it worked. Thank you everyone for your time.